# Is there such a thing as RNN-LSTM

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, lstm, rnn

From the title, I wanna know if there's such a thing as RNN-LSTM. I know that they are their own thing but I've yet to know if there's such a "combination".

For context, I was reading a research paper and there was this passage (source below): RNN-LSTM (Hochreiter and Schmidhuber 1997): The Recurrent Neural Network using LSTM cell. We combine an LSTM layer and a dense layer to perform multivariate time series forecasting.

Source: Cheng, J., Huang, K., & Zheng, Z. (2020). Towards Better Forecasting by Fusing Near and Distant Future Visions. Proceedings of the AAAI Conference on Artificial Intelligence, 34(04), 3593–3600. https://doi.org/10.1609/aaai.v34i04.5766

Answer (score 1):

RNN is a general term for Neural network architecture having recurrent connections. This architecture is built from a single entity called "cell". These so called cells are used repeatedly and connected in recursive fashion.

LSTM is one of these type of cells. If you build a RNN using LSTM cells, it becomes LSTM RNN. So basically as long as you use LSTM as a basic entity for building a RNN, it will be called LSTM RNN.